# How Is 4d Cartography Best Applied to Add Value to the Viewer?

Tags: cartography, visualisation, 3d-map, research

I’m about to write my bachelor thesis in Geography with my main focus being GIS. I’m still in the process of finding a good topic. My supervisor and I narrowed it down to 4D cartography and if and how gaming engines like Unity can be used to create interactive 4D maps, the third dimension not necessarily having to be space and the fourth being time of course.

The main focus of my project is the technical feasibility of gaming engines for 4D maps, but I need to show it on an actual experiment.

So I’ve read a ton of articles throughout the last two weeks about 4D, which seems to be still a relatively new subject in the GIS world. There seem to be not even a hand full of articles about actual implementations of experiments with 4D maps (e.g. Bernd Resch et al. 2013: Towards 4D Cartography Four dimensional Dynamic Maps for Understanding Spatio temporal Correlations in Lightning Events).

Now I’m trying to come up with my own idea for an experiment but can’t really come up with something that is really convincing to me.

- Visualize changes in population distribution over time through some
  sort of “topographic” map, where “mountains” are high population
  density. Lack of sufficient data makes it difficult.
- Visualize changes in residential rents in cities. Again, lack of sufficient
  data makes it difficult.
- Visualize sea level rise or flooding (there is already lots of software to simulate this)
- Heat development in the city during summer (this one I can actually see a usefulness, because the architecture can have a big influence on heat development and microclimate and would have to be visualized in 3D)
- Traffic accidents in a 3D map over time.

I feel like I just need some more inspiration of what useful stuff can be done with 4D. I figured there might be some experts here who are active in 4D cartography, maybe you can think of some other examples, where 4D can be usefully applied so that it produces added value to the viewer of the map?

Comment: Your question is relevant, but very broad and will most likely be closed...

Comment: If that's so, do you have any suggestions where I can contact the community to ask this question?

Comment: You need to decide on the variants of the sets of specific software in which you would like to simulate some behavior, then you need to break down the behavior of the model (situation) into simpler scenarios and only then ask specific questions... e.g. how to tie a 3D model (e.g. in the format of CityGML) using software, e.g. SketchUpPro, etc...(my examples are invented, just for example...)

Comment: And one more wish, you need to understand for which viewer you are trying, for everyone? For motorists? For pilots? For bicyclists? etc., it is important because each user sets specific requirements...

Comment: Yes, these are still things I need to determine, but that's already one step further of where I'm at right now. The question is, what practical examples are there, where 4D makes sense, over choosing 3D (X+Y axis + time) or even a static presentation of the data. I thought there might have been more people working with 4D that simply don't publicize as much in journals.